# How to display current date automatically in ASPxDateEdit Control on default loading

Tags: devexpress

I need to display the Current Date (17/Jun/2013) Automatically in the ASPxDateEdit Control by default while loading.

How to implement this?Any default property is there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please follow this example and modify according to your requirement:

```
<dx:ASPxDateEdit runat="server" ID="uniquedateid"  Width="95px"><ClientSideEvents Init="function(s,e){ s.SetDate(new Date());}" /> </dx:ASPxDateEdit>
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to look [here](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q428215). The `Date` property will solve your problem.